# Handling screen orientation properly in WIndows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I've finished my app and everything works properly, however I just realized my app does not act properly when the screen is rotated, which means its probably going to scale to different screen resolutions either. I used a blank page template when I designed it, and I can't find any documentation that doesn't talk about Windows Phone 8. What do I have to do to make sure my app scales and acts properly during rotations and different screen sizes? Last app I published was for Windows Phone 7

```
<Page
x:Class="SynagramsWindows8App.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SynagramsWindows8App"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/cute-clouds-seamless-pattern.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblMain" Margin="2,28,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SYNAGRAMS!" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Buxton Sketch" FontSize="72" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF085EF5"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnGameMode" Content="Game Modes" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="70,168,70,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF0E0474" FontFamily="Buxton Sketch" FontSize="48" Click="btnGameMode_Click" Foreground="#FF071570" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnInstructions" Content="Instructions" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="70,329,70,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FF0E0474" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Buxton Sketch" FontSize="48" Click="btnInstructions_Click" Foreground="#FF071570" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnTopScore" Content="Achievements" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="70,470,70,50" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FF0E0474" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Buxton Sketch" FontSize="48" Foreground="#FF071570" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Click="btnTopScore_Click">

    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Here is a link to the pics of portrait and landscape (going to fix font sizes later). I may just lock the screen to portrait.

[App main screen pics](http://1drv.ms/1EkAlpp)

Comment: You should add some additional information: are you targetting *RunTime* or *Silverlight*? What do you mean by 'not act properly'? What are your expectations, some code, probably xaml would be nice here. Also is it universal app? - if not you can remove windows-8.1 tag.

Comment: I'm targeting RunTime, after a few more test the app scales properly among screens of different sizes and resolution but when I change the orientation to landscape 2 buttons are off the screen.

Comment: Without the xaml code it is hard to say anything about the problem.

Comment: updated my post with the XAML and a link to the pics (couldn't post images here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded *Margins* which is nothing good when you want to make your app support different orientations/resolutions.

Consider using Rows/Columns in your grid, along with *Star* units for Height/Width, then it will scale automactically:

(I don't know how you wish your layout to look like, so I've put example values of Height)

```xml
<Grid>
   <Grid.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/cute-clouds-seamless-pattern.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
   </Grid.Background>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
       <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lblMain" Margin="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="SYNAGRAMS!" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="Buxton Sketch" FontSize="72" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF085EF5"/>
   <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnGameMode" Content="Game Modes" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF0E0474" FontFamily="Buxton Sketch" FontSize="48" Click="btnGameMode_Click" Foreground="#FF071570" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
   <Button Grid.Row="2" x:Name="btnInstructions" Content="Instructions" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FF0E0474" BorderThickness="1" FontFamily="Buxton Sketch" FontSize="48" Click="btnInstructions_Click" Foreground="#FF071570" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>    
   <!-- and so on -->
</Grid>
```

If you use Rows/Columns with *Star* as Height/Width then the space will be calculated according to screen. Please take a look at some tutorials and MSDN: 
[one](http://www.wpftutorial.net/gridlayout.html), [two](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/), [three](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514525(v=vs.90).aspx), [four](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745823(v=vs.110).aspx) and probably more.

Comment: Thanks, this is a hobby project so its pretty new to me. This worked well and I will have to research the grid design guidelines

Answer (score 0):

You can select which orientations your app supports by going to Package.appxmanifest and under "Supported rotations:" checking the orientations that your app works with.